# Why does adding to ascii adds up extra characters?

Tags: c, ascii

So, I tried to create a program in C which converts uppercase characters to lowercase, just by adding 32 to uppercase characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char user_inp[16];
  char final_res[16];
  int ascii;
  printf("%s", "Enter any string : ");
  scanf("%s", &user_inp);

  for (int i = 0; user_inp[i] != 0; i++){
    ascii = (int) user_inp[i];
    if (ascii < 91&& ascii > 64){
      ascii = ascii + 32;
    }
    final_res[i] = ascii;
  }

  printf("%s\n", final_res);

  return 0;
}
```

But when I run it, I get some extra jibrish results.

```
For example,
Input : Apple
Output : apple

But,
Input : Encyclopedia
Output : encyclopedia�U
```

What problem am I getting ? How can I fix this ?

Comment: You don't initialize `final_res` so the output string is not null-terminated and you get whatever happens to be in the memory after the string printed up to the first null that _is_ found.  Simplest fix: `char final_res[16] = "";`

Comment: There are a few things in your code that are bad practice: Never use magic numbers if not necessary. If you want to compare with `'A'`, use `>='A'`, not `>64`. If you want to convert upper and lower case letters, use standard function `tolower()` from `ctype.h`. While the chance to hit a non-ASCII system really is tiny, it's never a good idea to rely on such implementation defined details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C strings need to be null terminated. `user_inp` is. But `final_res` is not.